# Can we efficiently run HHL on a computational basis state without violating the BBBV theorem?

Tags: hhl-algorithm, bbbv

Recall that the [linear systems algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_algorithm_for_linear_systems_of_equations) of Harrow, Hassidim, and Lloyd purports to find a quantum state $|x\rangle$ proportional to $\vec x$, where $\vec x$ satisfies $A\vec x=\vec b$.  In addition to constraints on $A$, many other conditions need to be placed on $\vec b$.  In particular $|b\rangle$ must be *easily* prepared, e.g., with a Grover-Rudolph like algorithm.

Nonetheless in a footnote in "Quantum Machine Learning: Read the Fine Print" - [link to pdf](https://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/qml.pdf), Aaronson provides:

> $^1$If the HHL algorithm could be adapted to the case where (say) a single $b_i$ is $1$ and all the others are $0$, then it would contradict the impossibility of an exponential speedup for black-box quantum search, which was proved by Bennett, Bernstein, Brassard, and Vazirani.

But, it's not clear to me how a non-uniform $|b\rangle$ violates BBBV or causes trouble for HHL.  Indeed if I understand the very simple example illustrated beginning on page 2 the [HHL paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.3171), $|b\rangle$ and $|b'\rangle$ could be home vertices on appropriately defined graphs $A$ and $A'$, while a stochastic walk on these graphs could have much the same or significantly different dynamics (and hence, could have much the same or very different limiting distributions whose overlap can be measured with a SWAP test on $|x\rangle$ and $|x'\rangle$).

Accordingly, **where is my misunderstanding?**  Why couldn't HHL be applied to efficiently invert $A|x\rangle=|b\rangle$ where $|b\rangle=|00\cdots 0\rangle$ or some other fiducial basis state?

Added: this footnote may have been dropped from the Nature publication!  See comment from @gIS.

Comment: the algorithm itself doesn't depend on $|b\rangle$, so I don't see how the structure of $|b\rangle$ would change its efficiency. Maybe in that footnote they were thinking of the circuit preparing $|b\rangle$ as part of the algorithm? As in, it's hard to prepare a state $\sum_i b_i |i\rangle$ with a single peaked amplitude? That's still weird though (surely eg $|0\rangle$ can be prepared efficiently?). Maybe it's hard to be able to prepare *any* such circuit? As in, having a parametrised circuit $U_i$ such that $U_i |0\rangle=|i\rangle$ for all $i$?

Comment: @gIS Indeed a peaked solution $|x\rangle$ likely violates BBBV., but I don’t call $|b\rangle$ a solution vector.  This footnote in the paper has made its way into the English language [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_algorithm_for_linear_systems_of_equations) article on HHL, wherein the article refers to the “solution vector” $|b\rangle$ having to be uniform…

Comment: Maybe this footnote was dropped in the Nature version (I don’t have access beyond the paywall).

Comment: ah, you're right. The nature version has the discussion about preparing $|b\rangle$ in Box 1, second page, but there's no mention of BBBV or the associated quote.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Answer made Community-Wiki</sup>

---

Well, as indicated in the comments from @gIS, $|b\rangle$ needs to be efficiently prepared, but once $|b\rangle$ is provided the efficiency of the remaining portions of HHL algorithm is *independent* of $|b\rangle$.  It's straightforward to prepare $|00\cdots 0\rangle$ or any other known basis state, or indeed many other non-uniform states.

As worked out by @gIS and me in the comments, this footnote is not present in the Nature-published [version](https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys3272) of the paper, but the comment did make its way into the English-language [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_algorithm_for_linear_systems_of_equations) article on HHL as of August 31, 2023.

Perhaps with the reference to BBBV Aaronson had envisioned $A$ as a local Hamiltonian of a constraint-satisfaction problem (such as a [3CSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem)) with each unsatisfied clause having corresponding energy penalty - in such a case, BBBV generally precludes quickly determining the assignment with the fewest number of unsatisfied clauses.  Or, $U=\exp(-iA)$ could be a random permutation, in which case it would violate BBBV to quickly invert the permutation to find $|x\rangle$ such that $U|x\rangle=|00\cdots 0\rangle$.

But, those are issues with the structure of **$A$**, and not so much of $|b\rangle$.